# CSS. Correctly place icons above and below number

Tags: html, css

I want to place chevron-up and chevron-down icons very close to a number, I just can't do it correctly, please help.

This is what I have:

```
   ▲     
   5 Read Post
   ▼
```

I want the arrows to be closer to the number (very close). I've arrived to a partial solution, but the problem comes when the number is bigger, I want the arrows to be in the middle of the number, but I get something like this:

```
   ▲     
   534 Read Post
   ▼
```

The "partial solution" I have is available in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alejoss/sp469j1n/).
Also, I can't align a text "Read Post" to the vote's number, you will see in the fiddle.

I'm a backend developer and for now, terrible at CSS, I'd appreciate it if someone can explain me a little about what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You should include the relevant HTML and CSS you have tried *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `<p>` tag is probably what is forcing your text on to the next line, I would suggest to use `divs` with `float:left`, `text-align:center` and `auto` margins.

Based on your fiddle, I changed it to this as a starting point, hopefully you can adjust it from here:

HTML:

```
<a class = "link_wrapper">
<span class = "votes_post">
    <i class = "up fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
    <div>
    255
    </div>
    <i class = "down fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
</span>
<div class = "text">Read Post.</div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.link_wrapper{
  width: 340px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.votes_post{
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.votes_post i {
  font-weight: lighter;
}
.votes_post div {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.text{
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for making the effort and using the fiddle as reference. The only change I did to you code was `.text{margin-top: 25px}`, that way it is correctly aligned. Anyway, this is the most understandable solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/aGcyE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>

p {
  width: 340px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a, span {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}

span {position: relative; padding: 20px 0;}

span::before, span::after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
}

span::before {
    content: "\f077";
    top: 0;
}

span::after {
    content: "\f078";
    bottom: 0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><span>255</span> <a href="#">Read Post</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```